# Annotation Validation Error when trying to install Vault on OpenShift

Tags: openshift, hashicorp-vault

Following this [tutorial](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/how-to-use-vault-to-access-encrypted-variables-on-openshift/) on installing Vault with Helm on OpenShift, I encountered the following error after executing the command:

```
bash
helm install vault hashicorp/vault -n $VAULT_NAMESPACE -f my_values.yaml
```

For the config:

```
values.yaml
bash
echo '# Custom values for the Vault chart
global:
  # If deploying to OpenShift
  openshift: true
server:
  dev:
    enabled: true
  serviceAccount:
    create: true
    name: vault-sa
injector:
  enabled: true
authDelegator:
  enabled: true' > my_values.yaml
```

The error:

```
$ helm install vault hashicorp/vault -n $VAULT_NAMESPACE -f values.yaml
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: ClusterRole "vault-agent-injector-clusterrole" in namespace "" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; annotation validation error: key "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace" must equal "my-vault-1": current value is "my-vault-0"
```

What exactly is happening, or how can I reset this specific name space to point to the right release namespace?

Answer (score 1):

Have you by chance tried the exact same thing before, because that is what the error is hinting.
If we dissect the error, we get the to the root of the problem:

```
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists.
```

So something on the cluster already exists that you were trying to deploy via the helm chart.

```
Unable to continue with install:
```

Helm is aborting due to this failure

```
ClusterRole "vault-agent-injector-clusterrole" in namespace "" exists
```

So the cluster role `vault-agent-injector-clusterrole` that the helm chart is supposed to put onto the cluster already exsits. ClusterRoles aren't namespace specific, hence the "namespace" is blank.

```
and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; annotation validation error: key "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace" must equal "my-vault-1": current value is "my-vault-0"
```

The default behavior is to try to import existing resources that this chart requires, but it is not possible, because the owner of that `ClusterRole` is different from the deployment.

To fix this, you can remove the existing deployment of your chart and then give it an other try and it should work as expected.

Make sure all resources are gone. For this particular one you can check with `kubectl get clusterroles`

Answer (score 1):

It can be fixed by this list of commands, execute it after deploying first instance, then deploy the second one

```
kubectl delete mutatingwebhookconfiguration vault-agent-injector-cfg
kubectl delete clusterrolebinding vault-server-binding
kubectl delete clusterrolebinding vault-agent-injector-binding
kubectl delete clusterrole vault-agent-injector-clusterrole
```